# unity pathfinding

Tags: unity, path-finding

I have the navmesh and all set up in my unity project but as is I only know how to give it a target to go to, what I want is for it to randomly walk around my scene any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Pick a random position and move to it. When you get there pick a new position and move to that.